# Setting author when creating a new node via Cron

Tags: cron

I'm creating a new node using hook_cron(). It all works except the node author is always set as anonymous (uid = 0). How can I assign a user to the new node, with say uid 21 for example?

Below is the node creation code that I have in a function that gets called within hook_cron().

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $type;
$node->title = "Some node title";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->uid = 21;
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'html_text';

$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['value'] = $some_value;
$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'plain_text';

$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Even though I state `$node->uid = 21;`, it always results in an anonymous author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

Either set the uid after the [node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_submit/7) call and before [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7), or set `$node->name` to the username of the user that should be the author. The reason is that `node_submit()` will set the uid of the node based on the value of `$node->name`.

Comment: I used $node->name and it fixed the problem perfectly. After looking at node_submit() it makes sense now why it was setting the author as anon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `$node->uid` before calling [node_object_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7), but that function contains the following code.

```
global $user;
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
```

You need to set `$node->uid` after calling `node_object_prepare()`, and thus your code should be like the following one.

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $type;
$node->title = "Some node title";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->uid = 21;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'html_text';

$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['value'] = $some_value;
$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'plain_text';

$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Be sure you don't set `$node->name` when you set `$node->uid` at the same time, or [node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_submit/7) will set `$node->uid` with the following code.

```
  if (isset($node->name)) {
    if ($account = user_load_by_name($node->name)) {
      $node->uid = $account->uid;
    }
    else {
      $node->uid = 0;
    }
  }
```

What is the difference between setting `$node->uid`, and setting `$node->name`? The difference is that in the first case you don't cause Drupal to call [user_load_by_name()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7) all times you call `node_submit()`. This means you are not causing Drupal to call [DrupalDefaultEntityController::load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3a%3aload/7), and [DrupalDefaultEntityController::buildQuery()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3a%3abuildQuery/7). The first function invokes some hooks that are used to alter the query, such as [hook_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7).
As you seem to set the same user as author of more than one node, it would be better if you call `user_load_by_name()` as in the following code.

```
$account = user_load_by_name($name);

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $type;
$node->title = "Some node title";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);

$node->uid = $account->uid;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = '';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'html_text';

$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['value'] = $some_value;
$node->field_quote[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'plain_text';

$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

That is the code I would use if you are not using other code that returns you the user object to use for the node author.